# Blend nested content over grandparent of different size

Tags: qml, qtquick2, fragment-shader, blending

Given QML content with a nested hierarchy, how can I perform a 'screen' [`Blend`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-blend.html) from content that is not a sibling of the content?

For example, given this layout:

```
Window {
  Image { id:bg; source:'qrc:/bg'; anchors.fill:parent }
  Item {
    id:header
    width:parent.width; height:parent.height*0.2; anchors.top:parent.top
    Image {
      id:logo; source:'qrc:/logo'
      height:parent.height; width:height
      anchors.left:parent.left
    }
  }
}
```

How can I screen the logo over the background, **without screen blending any other content in the header**?

[image: visual representation of the code layering content]

[image: composited result, showing the logo screen blended onto the background]

*Bonus points if your answer works when the `header` is a component in a separate file, e.g. `Header.qml`.*

---

With the following code, the full background gets resized to the size of the logo before compositing:

```
Window {
  visible:true; width:800; height:600
  Image { id:bg; source:'qrc:/bg'; anchors.fill:parent }
  Item {
    id:header
    width:parent.width; height:parent.height*0.2; anchors.top:parent.top
    Image {
      id:logo; source:'qrc:/logo'
      height:parent.height; width:height
      anchors.left:parent.left
      visible:false
    }
    Blend {
      anchors.fill: logo
      source: bg
      foregroundSource: logo
      mode: 'screen'
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a guess that the answer may be to use [Item Layers with a `ShaderEffect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html#shadereffect-and-item-layers), but I haven't yet found a working combination of shader parameters and code that will sample the correct region of the background.